# Issues with undefined reference NDK

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, sdl, sdl-ttf

Ok I know that this has been brought up.  Yet mine does not seem to be addressed.
Before we start let it be known the following:

- OS: Win7 (x86)
- IDE: Eclipse Juno (4.2)
- NDK: r8e
- Android API: 17 (Jelly Bean 4.2)

I am trying to get SDL_ttf to fully compile.  I am just trying to build this project and get on with things and after much struggling with getting it to recognize that certain files do in fact exist exactly where they say they exists.  I am now getting

**Updated**:

```
17:06:42 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project OmegaDice ****
"C:\\android-ndk-r8e\\ndk-build.cmd" V=1 clean all all 
FIND: Parameter format not correct
Clean: SDL2 [armeabi]
Clean: SDL2_ttf [armeabi]
Clean: freetype [armeabi]
Clean: main [armeabi]
Clean: stlport_shared [armeabi]
Clean: stlport_static [armeabi]
del /f/q .\libs\armeabi\libSDL2.so    >NUL 2>NUL
Install        : libSDL2.so => libs/armeabi/libSDL2.so
copy /b/y ".\obj\local\armeabi\libSDL2.so" ".\libs\armeabi\libSDL2.so" > NUL
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-strip --strip-unneeded  ./libs/armeabi/libSDL2.so
"Compile thumb : SDL2_ttf <= SDL_ttf.c
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o.d -fpic -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -no-canonical-prefixes -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -mthumb -Os -g -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -Ijni/SDL_ttf -Ijni/SDL_ttf/../SDL/include -Ijni/SDL_ttf/../freetype/include -Ijni/SDL_ttf/include -IC:/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport -IC:/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl//gabi++/include -Ijni/SDL_ttf -DANDROID -Os -Wa,--noexecstack  -IC:/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/include -c  jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c -o ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o 
SharedLibrary  : libSDL2_ttf.so
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -Wl,-soname,libSDL2_ttf.so -shared --sysroot=C:/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o ./obj/local/armeabi/libfreetype.a -lgcc ./obj/local/armeabi/libSDL2.so -no-canonical-prefixes  -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now  -LC:/android-ndk-r8e/platforms/android-14/arch-arm/usr/lib -lz -lc -lm -o ./obj/local/armeabi/libSDL2_ttf.so
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:590: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Get_Char_Index'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:592: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Load_Glyph'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:656: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Outline_Transform'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:662: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Get_Glyph'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:663: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Stroker_New'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:667: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Stroker_Set'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:669: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Glyph_Stroke'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:671: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Stroker_Done'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:673: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Glyph_To_Bitmap'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:676: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Done_Glyph'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:682: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Render_Glyph'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function Find_Glyph:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:885: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Done_Glyph'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_Init:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:334: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Init_FreeType'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_CloseFont:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:915: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Done_Face'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_OpenFontIndexRW:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:420: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Open_Face'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_OpenFontIndexRW:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:442: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Set_Charmap'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_OpenFontIndexRW:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:448: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Set_Char_Size'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_OpenFontIndexRW:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:457: error: undefined reference to 'FT_MulFix'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_OpenFontIndexRW:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:458: error: undefined reference to 'FT_MulFix'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_OpenFontIndexRW:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:460: error: undefined reference to 'FT_MulFix'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_OpenFontIndexRW:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:462: error: undefined reference to 'FT_MulFix'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_OpenFontIndexRW:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:474: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_GlyphIsProvided:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:1103: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Get_Char_Index'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_SizeUTF8:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:1204: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_RenderUTF8_Solid:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:1390: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_RenderUTF8_Shaded:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:1568: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_RenderUTF8_Blended:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:1732: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Get_Kerning'
C:/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld.exe: ./obj/local/armeabi/objs/SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.o: in function TTF_Quit:jni/SDL_ttf/SDL_ttf.c:2140: error: undefined reference to 'FT_Done_FreeType'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libSDL2_ttf.so] Error 1

17:07:20 Build Finished (took 37s.757ms)
```

**jni/SDL_ttf/Android.mk**:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := SDL2_ttf
FREETYPE := $(LOCAL_PATH)/freetype
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH) $(LOCAL_PATH)/../SDL/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../freetype/include $(LOCAL_PATH)/include

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -Os

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := SDL_ttf.c

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := SDL2
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := freetype
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

So if anyone has any helpful suggestions as to why this is happening or how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please run `ndk-build V=1 clean all` to reveal the actual link command, and try to format the output so that the lines do not wrap together (really hard to read now)

Comment: use Ctrl-K, not Ctrl-Q to wrap your pasted text

Comment: where is libfreetype.a?

Comment: @CoderBear: sorry, I didn't see your reply... Anyway, you use a local static library __freetype__, but in your build log it is not compiled. So, probably, this `obj/local/armeabi/libfreetype.a` file does not contain the necessary objects and functions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
FIND: Parameter format not correct
```

so freetype is not compiled.

You are building in Windows, so the `find` command being executed is the Windows version, which has a different syntax.

You need to download a `find` program that has the same syntax of the unix one.
e.g. from here:
http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/

Then you need to force freetype Android.mk to use the new `find`:

change:

```
APP_SUBDIRS := $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(shell find $(LOCAL_PATH)/src -type d))
```

to

```
APP_SUBDIRS := $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(shell PATH_TO_UNIXLIKE_FIND\find $(LOCAL_PATH)/src -type d))
```

e.g.

```
APP_SUBDIRS := $(patsubst $(LOCAL_PATH)/%, %, $(shell c:\unixtools\usr\local\wbin\find $(LOCAL_PATH)/src -type d))
```